# The largest interval in which function $f(x)=\cos^2x$ is strictly decreasing

Tags: calculus

The largest interval in which function $f(x)=\cos^2x$ is strictly decreasing on :

(a) $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$

(b) $[0,\frac{\pi}{2})$

(c) $(0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$

(d) $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$

My approach is : clearly for $x\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2}) ,$ $0<\cos x<1$ implies  $0<\cos^2 x<1$ and $f^\prime <0$ hence decreasing ,

Now the doubt points are $x=0$ and $x=\frac{\pi}{2}, $  for $0<\frac{\pi}{2}$, $f(0)>f(\frac{\pi}{2}) $ and function is not repeating any other value hence option (a) should be the answer. But some books are claiming (d) option only

Comment: It's maximum and minimum so after it the function is bounded so d is correct

Comment: for every  $ x_1<x_2 $ such that $x_1,x_2 \in [o, \frac{\pi}{2}],$  $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$

Comment: Is there any other rule to check strictly monotonic when boundary points are  included?

Answer (score 3):

The usual definition say that a function $f(x):\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is strictly decreasing in  an interval $I$ if for  $a,b \in I\;,\; b>a$ we have $f(b)<f(a)$.

Using such definition your function is strictly decreasing in the interval $[0,\pi/2]$, so (a) is the correct answer.

Maybe that the answer (d) is ''justified'' by the fact that $x=0$ and $x=\pi/2$ are [stationary points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_point), and a function is considered strictly decreasing on a point only if the slope at this point is negative. But , in my opinion, this is not a good definition because the notion of decreasing ( or increasing)  is independent from the derivability of the function.

Comment: At the end point, we cant talk of differentiability as tangent is not unique

Answer (score 0):

**Strictly decreasing** means $f^\prime(x)<0$. So, $f^\prime(x)=-2 \sin (x) \cos (x)$ and $f^\prime(0)=f^\prime(\pi/2)=0$, which excludes those points from the interval where $f(x)$ is Strictly decreasing. Therefore, the answer is (d).